# Desire2Learn Connection via Android

Tags: android, desire2learn, valence

I am trying to connect to d2l via android. (I normally use C# but have decided to try an android application).

I have tried using the java client library compiling it and putting the .jar file into my libs folder with in the android project but the app crashes whenever I try to create an authenticated URI.

Anyone have any ideas? tips? I've searched for an example but haven't found one yet.

Thanks!

There is nothing being output to the console but this is what I get in the Logs hopefully this is what you're looking for:

```
04-16 17:05:39.690: W/dalvikvm(2118): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3861: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;.encodeBase64 ([BZZ)[B
04-16 17:05:39.690: D/dalvikvm(2118): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0010
04-16 17:05:39.730: W/dalvikvm(2118): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c6700)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-183
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at com.d2lvalence.idkeyauth.implementation.D2LSigner.getBase64HashString(D2LSigner.java:40)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at com.d2lvalence.idkeyauth.implementation.D2LUserContext.buildAuthenticatedUriQueryString(D2LUserContext.java:129)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at com.d2lvalence.idkeyauth.implementation.D2LUserContext.getQueryString(D2LUserContext.java:163)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at com.d2lvalence.idkeyauth.implementation.D2LUserContext.createAuthenticatedUri(D2LUserContext.java:93)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at com.example.d2lprofileupdate.D2LRest.GetName(D2LRest.java:100)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at com.example.d2lprofileupdate.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:32)
04-16 17:05:39.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2118):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-16 17:05:39.820: D/libEGL(2118): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
04-16 17:05:39.840: D/libEGL(2118): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-16 17:05:39.870: D/libEGL(2118): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
04-16 17:05:39.900: D/OpenGLRenderer(2118): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It's possible that without a lot of back and forth this won't really be a concrete Question resulting in a concrete Answer (that is, the concrete question might not be determinable for some time). As a result, I'd encourage you to try looking further into this in the Valence User Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/valenceusers) where more discussion and forensic conversation can take place. D2L experts also monitor and contribute there, too.

Comment: We've had a problem like this and solved it. I just wanted to validate that he was having the same problem before proposing a solution. There is a small problem with the Java library on Android.